# Scenarios for Visual Studio's ‘Clean Solution’ Option

Tags: visual-studio

My understanding is that Rebuild = Clean + Build. What are the likeliest reasons for offering ‘Clean Solution’ as a separate option, since rebuild does the same thing? I gave it some thought, and the only reason I could come up with was that some solutions can be fairly large and it may be time-consuming to do a clean AND a rebuild, but if you do a clean you'd have to (re)build anyway, right? Thanks, and happy holidays to all.

Comment: nice question; one thing to note from the answers: a lot of the answers assume the temp/output files are in the same directory, or a subdirectory, as where the project and source reside. While this is indeed default behaviour in VS, I think you're better of to build in a dedicated directory outside the source tree: keeps the tree free of non-soure files, no false entries in sourcecontrol, no debug/release dirs all over the place, and you can delete all compiler generated stuff with one click.

Comment: @stijn: Thanks for the feedback and the suggestion. I can see the value of "calling the shots" in terms of how the build output target is defined. Regards, Phil.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247457/difference-between-rebuild-and-clean-build-in-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clean Solution is like `msbuild /t:clean` and `make clean`, so it's useful in the same situations.

- Your build is a little broken, such that a generated file is placed in a common directory. When you switch configurations, you first clean the old configuration and then build the new one.
- You want to send someone a copy of your solution
- You don't have source control, but you want to checkpoint your solution before continuing
- You are modifying your project files by hand and want to make sure they work properly
- You created a new solution, worked on it for a day, and are now ready to put it in source control. Before you "add all files", you want to remove the generated files.
- You are short on disk space, and want to discard unnecessary files. Suppose you have a small SSD and several large solutions, or if you want to change configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and thanks also to Eduardo Scoz, Jason Williams, and Kevin and for your feedback, I appreciate it. Regards, Phil.

Answer (score 5):

I've used it several times to cleanup a new project before committing it to a repository (svn, or TFS).

Answer (score 3):

I could only come up with one :(

If you want to zip your solution directory, and don't want to include all the temporary files/compiled binaries/etc ?

Answer (score 2):

Clean gets rid of all the object files, so:

- you can clean and then copy the project's files without the object files being included in your copy (although clean may still leave some compiler-generated files around).
- you can do a release build occasionally (e.g. once a month) and then clean it away to get rid of the clutter in your project until the next time you need to build it.
- You can do a clean and then build and do something else in between
- You can do a clean when you want to quickly make sure that the next build will be a full rebuild, but when you don't want to start the build now (e.g. clean the project before you go home to be sure that you won't forget to do a rebuild in the morning when you start work)
- You can clean multiple projects (libraries etc) before you go back and build them - so you know you have a truly clean build, rather than several rebuilds that may have been affected by old junk that was lying aroud in a referenced library (ok, this one is grasping at straws - as long as you rebuild the dependencies before the dependants it shouldn't matter :-)

Having said that, clean isn't really useful very often - especially as free disk space becomes ever bigger, the pressures of olden days (e.g. keeping your project on a floppy disk and making enough room available to continue working) are no longer relevant.