# For a Visual Studio ASP.NET solution, Rebuild (or Clean, then Build) doesn't seem to fix issues with binary mismatch for debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, build-process

I from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247457/difference-between-rebuild-and-clean-build-in-visual-studio-2008/1311841#1311841) what the differences are between Build, ReBuild and Clean solution, but I'm not clear about whether it only updates the binaries in the project dir(s) or also makes sure the ones in the IIS webroot, caches, etc. are replaced.

Sometimes, I'll add a breakpoint and attach to the IIS process to debug and it will warn me that the loaded binary doesn't match the solution, even though I rebuilt. I have to hit a page with my browser to fix it (that causes ASP.NET to rebuild the binary). Why isn't the binary in IIS getting replaced when I build in VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<system.web>
      <hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false"/>
</system.web>
```