# Quickly Compiling Changes for Couple of Files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using .NET Framework and C# and working on a large project. The application compile takes forever. Currently, I don't have time to see what is going wrong. But is there anyway that if I change 2-3 files I can compile the application quickly.

It is a web application. The solution has 6-7 other projects.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're doing a Build and not a Rebuild or Publish, right?

Comment: Could you quantify "forever?"

Comment: I am doing a build! Forever means 5 minutes!

Comment: actually I am changing just a single file which is a code behind file do I still need to build the whole project it is .aspx.vb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you "must" rebuild(what ever that got changed) in order for your changes to take effect.

Also, as a side note:

- Break into modules/assemblies, compile only that assembly which got changed!
- If your existing change is in some specific assembly then build only that assembly.

Comment: Even if I build only the assembly that got changed it takes forever since it has references to other assemblies.

Comment: This is not working! I uncomment some code and now I need to compile again. I am compiling a single project and it is taking 5 minutes!

Comment: @JohnDoe: Use `Build` and donot use 'Rebuild`; if the references of the project has not changed, the compiler will not *recompile* them; *rebuild=clean + build*. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247457/difference-between-rebuild-and-clean-build-in-visual-studio-2008

Comment: Thanks! Actually I am using msbuild.exe command line for building and it is working much much faster.

Answer (score 0):

"unload" the projects (right click on the project in the solution explorer). The project isn't removed from your solution, but it won't be compiled either.

Comment: If the project the unloaded can the main project still refer to the dlls of that project.