# XML File not deleted while cleaning a solution in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, wpf

I am Creating XML File for saving the credentials.

```
  private void CreateCredentialFile()
   {
        string path = @"Assets\CredentialFile.xml";
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("ConferenceRooms"));
         XElement newRoom = new XElement("ConferenceRoom",
                                           new XElement("Email",SelectedConfRoom.EmailId),
                                           new XElement("Password", SelectedConfRoom.Password)
                                       );
        doc.Element("ConferenceRooms").Add(newRoom);
        doc.Save(path);
   }
```

But If I clean the solution means this file still present in my output directory. I want to this file get removed while cleaning the solution. Is there anyway to remove this file while cleaning the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Skeet:

> Clean solution will remove the build artifacts from the previous
>   build. If there are any other files in the build target directories
>   (bin and obj) they may not be removed, but actual build artifacts are.

Reference: [Difference between Build Solution, Rebuild Solution, and Clean Solution in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095901/difference-between-build-solution-rebuild-solution-and-clean-solution-in-visua)

What it actually means is that as long as you're manually creating files into your application the *output* folder, they will not be removed when using the **Clean Solution** command, but only those files which generated by the Visual Studio MS-BUILD.

But, you can add the following section to the project in question in order to perform custom cleaning:

```
<Target Name="AfterClean">
    <Delete Files="$(TargetDir)\*.txt" />
</Target>
```

Comment: In spite of divine nature of Jon Skeet, direct citations are not answers. You can easily mark question as duplicate.

Comment: Where did you take this rule from? Due to my respect for Jon I quoted him.

Comment: @Dineshbalan You're welcome! tell me, did you customize something with my code or it simply worked for you as is?

Comment: @YairNevet I customized something like you told

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this. If your goal is to remove the XML file prior to building the solution, you can use a Pre-build event. Navigate to your project properties > Compile tab > Build Events (button lower right). In the Build Events window, you can add a command or script to do the necessary pre-build cleanup. This is quite flexible and allows you to externally manage resource files that aren't considered as part of the actual project output.

Comment: I don't want to remove the file while build. I want to remove the file while clean the solution only.