# Does build in visual studio/c# , rebuild it's dependencies? Why do I need to use clean sometimes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I understand that build will compile and create an assembly that then will be executed. What I'm not clear on is why sometimes, even though I'm referencing say some web page logic, if altered, I will still need to rebuild the entire solution for the changes to appear. Why isn't building the main application project, that references the target project, not receiving the new changes when I execute it?

Also as a second question, why do I need to clean and build my solution sometimes?

Thanks, I know this is rather vague...

Comment: Not fair to down-vote this question.  If you have used VS long enough ... this question makes perfect sense.

Comment: Sounds like a variation on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095901/difference-between-build-solution-rebuild-solution-and-clean-solution-in-visua

Answer (score 0):

The clean functionality in VS doesn't really do what it is usually needed for.  It should delete the intermediary files and folders.  In my opinion it should also clean out the temp files for ASP.NET applications ... but it doesn't do that either.

A rebuild is often needed because of linkage to other DLL's.  A build will only update the applications and dependent references that VS can detect.  Often you will get manifest mismatches when VS doesn't detect the changes accordingly.  Then you need to do a rebuild to resolve the issue.

Often times (especially in ASP.NET applications) you will get build time errors that are incorrect or link time errors.  Emptying out the ASP.NET temp folder resolves those errors.

I've yet to get a clean process to ever solve my problems.  Good luck.