# visual studio web express 2013 - reverted to old code

Tags: asp.net

I have been working on a solution in Visual Studio 2013 Web express for past several months now. It was opening my recent changes until yesterday when I loaded the solution and it was showing all .aspx html and code behind programming from 3 months back. I can no longer access my recent solution. Its frustrating having to rework everything. Has anyone encountered this problem or can you suggest a solution how I can get my updated version?

Comment: Backup your projects

Comment: This all depemds on more information. Was this solution on shared server?  Where is solution stored? There is usually versionIng of solutions. if the code is correct in the file, rebuild your solution as in  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095901/difference-between-build-solution-rebuild-solution-and-clean-solution-in-visua)

Comment: the solution was stored in projects folder within VS folder, but it no longer presents the updated codes.