# MSBuild: Do I need Target Rebuild?

Tags: unit-testing, build, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I use a build file to build and test my project.
I have a **Compile-Target** which has this line **"Targets = "Rebuild"**. Do I really need this line? Using Visual Studio I know that I can clean a Solution and build it again, or I can just rebuild the solution.
In my msbuild-file I **delete** my main folder **BuildArtifacts** before creating him again. I used this [Tutorial](https://www.infoq.com/articles/MSBuild-1) and I don't know why he uses Target=Rebuild?
This is my build file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="RunUnitTests" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"> 

  <!-- Falls Eigenschaften nicht gesetzt -> Release & Any CPU als default-->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- All the stuff go into my main folder -->
  <Target Name="Init" DependsOnTargets="Clean">
    <MakeDir Directories="@(BuildArtifacts)" />
  </Target>

  <!-- delete my main folder -->
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="@(BuildArtifactsDir)" />
  </Target>

  <!-- delete NUnit-Files -->
  <Target Name="CleanAfter">
    <RemoveDir Directories="@(NunitDir)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Compile" DependsOnTargets="Init">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionFile)" 
    Targets="Rebuild" 
    Properties="OutDir=%(BuildArtifactsDir.FullPath);
    Configuration=$(Configuration);
    Platform=$(BuildPlatform)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="RunUnitTests" DependsOnTargets="Compile">
         <Exec Command='"@(NUnitConsole)" "@(UnitTestsDLL)" --result=console-test.xml --work=BuildArtifacts' />
         <CallTarget Targets="CleanAfter" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your own needs: do you need the whole solution to be rebuilt or not? Arguably, on a build server, you want to do a complete clean/rebuild after every commit to make sure the codebase is sane. Removing just the output directory (I assume that is what the *Clean* starget does) doesn't necessarily remove all object files as well since they typically go into the intermediate directory which might not be the same as the output directory.

Comment: oh ok, thanks! So if I want to clean and rebuild it, I should use "Targets="Rebuild""?

Comment: Yes it will call Clean and Build targets for all projects in the solution, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095901/difference-between-build-solution-rebuild-solution-and-clean-solution-in-visua