# Incorrect display of problem - The name does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have been creating a project in blazor for some time (visual studio 2019, version 16.11.2) and at the end I started getting an error related to a context that does not exist, but the functions work by themselves and the program compiles. Due to this error, method hints are not displayed. I guess it's caused by something from visual studio or IntelliSense, but I don't know what exactly.
[errors here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xt0u.png)

Comment: I think we need more proof. According to the error messages, I'd say the program does not compile and you're running a build from an earlier time. Use "[clean solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3095935/480982)" and possibly delete the `bin` folder to make sure the executable is really gone. Then build again and see if the exe exists.

Comment: If it's an Intellisense problem (that does happen) you can just restart VS. But they look like real errors.

Comment: Try this - close VS, delete the `bin`,`obj` and `.vs` folders - restart VS

Comment: Removing the bin, obj, .vs folders helped, thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.