# How to see the commands issued in Visual Studio for "Build > Rebuild Solution" menu option?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working with Visual Studio Community 2019 in Windows 10. I have a solution which has multiple projects of different types.

I open that solution in Visual Studio Community 2019. Then click on "Build > Rebuild Solution" menu option to rebuild it. In the **Output** tab I can see output from ***Build***. That output shows me the result of rebuild but it does not show me what command(s) were issued to start the rebuild. How  can I see those command(s) issued by Visual Studio?

I want to know what happens so I can write a script (window .bat or powershell) to do it outside of VStudio if needed.

Thanks

Comment: There's not much difference between build and rebuild. Basically, "build" means if stuff needs to be updated then do a rebuild, and "rebuild" means do a rebuild always. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17781143/395718

Comment: Do you just want to know what happens, or are you asking because you want to automate them outside of VStudio (eg. Jenkins build)

Comment: @tgolisch I want to know what happens so that I can write a script (window .bat or powershell) to do it outside of VStudio if needed

Answer (score 2):

Change the Verbosity level of Build output.

You can access it from the "Tools > Options" menu option; then "Projects and Solutions > Build and Run" section; then "MSBuild project build output verbosity" field.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio builds use MSBuild. You could increase the build verbosity to get a massive dump of text, but I recommend using the [Project System Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProjectSystemTools) plugin to record binary build logs for export to [MSBuild Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/).