# C# Console Application build but not launch application

Tags: c#, console

I have a simple Console Application write with C-Sharp language (Visual Studio 2013):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I press F5 or click Start button, my project was built, but not launch.
Sometime, Ouput windows says:

```
Error   12  Could not copy "obj\Debug\HelloWorld.exe" to "bin\Debug\HelloWorld.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

Error   13  Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\HelloWorld.exe" to "bin\Debug\HelloWorld.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\HelloWorld.exe' because it is being used by another process.
```

but when I write Windows Form Application, my project was built and launch normally ???

Why? and How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Clean your project and try again.

Comment: I tried but still not solved

Comment: It says that the file is being used by another process. Try to terminate all processes except visual studio then find out which process causes the problem.

Comment: Possible your application is still running, so the executable is locked. Please run Task Manager and check for HelloWorld.exe, if found then terminate it.

Comment: I tried restart my computer, reopen my project, but it just build & start normally the first time, and then same problem show :(

Comment: OK, i am going to try to kill in taskmanager

Comment: Can't solve :( The project was built, but not launch :(

Comment: Maybe it is launching, but in minimized window, according some default or specific setting on your computer/user. a) Start, then check in startmanager if it is running. if yes, then it starts just invisible/minimized. T. b) Kill all HelloWorld.exe, then try to start is ctrl+f5, what do you see

Comment: No, it isn't launched, there is no new process in taskmanager :(

Comment: try to make clean solution and then build and press F5

Comment: I tried. But not solved. :(

Comment: Is it possible that the user in the computer doesn't have access to the folder where the executable is deployed? Are you admin?

Comment: Can you try to copy the whole project folder to another location and start it from there?

Comment: I'm using Administrator user, in location bin\debug, i can't run, copy, cut or delete anything, but if i sign out user and login again, i can do it ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047079/visual-studio-rebuild-all-failed/24108431#24108431

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to windows keeping the process open. Your only option is to try and kill all processes of your app in task manager->processes.

The next thing to try is to simply change the build from debug to release, this should build another executable in the release folder as opposed to debug. By no means is this a silver bullet but, hopefully a sufficient workaround.

Before you try the release build, attempt to try and fix the problem. I've seen windows moan at just having my debug folder open and my exe selected because I suspect the thumbnail was being displayed thus being "used" in windows etc.

Comment: Oh and try to delete everything in the debug folder. However, leave the files containing vshost

Comment: In debug folder, I can't do anything, but when I log off user and sign in again, i can do it.

Comment: This sounds to me as if you might be having some permission trouble in the folder. Once all deleted try to right click on your project and click build. If you are not able to, try rebuild. After, that it's to try release, I did note you tried clean which sometimes solves this

Comment: When I create new project, the problem will show again, I'm trying to repair Visual Studio, but a new problem is shown, I can't delete anything in my project folder, ultil i sign out and login again, i don't know why and how to solve this :(

Comment: Wow, it sounds like something really strange is going on. The last thing I can think of is simply to right click your visual studio shortcut, and run as administrator to see if it helps anything at all. Otherwise you might even need to go as far as a re-installation/repair of the installation

Answer (score 0):

I found reason and solve for my problem.
I tried to restart Application Experience Service and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Please restart yor Visual Studio and then try again. It will work and delete your bin/debug folder again.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with this issue.
That happeneds when an instance of software is running whether by **visual studio** or by **your self**

**solution :**

you should find your application name in the processes of task manager

your's is :

> HelloWorld.exe

select that and click on the end task button

now you can start debugging and running you'r app.

at least worked for me.