# Does Build mean that the exe file is over-written

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Still unsure about all the `BUILD` options.

If I just want to over-write the `.exe` file in the `Solution`s `bin\Debug` directory all I need to do is choose `Build` ?

`ReBuild` has another purpose?

`Clean` I assume is if it has bugged at a point creating problems within the Solution?

I've referred to this [page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cyz1h6zd.aspx) but it doesn't refer to specific directories within the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Build** - does incremental builds (doesn't bother updating stuff that hasn't changed)

**Rebuild** - does a *Clean* then a *Build*

**Clean** - just clears all intermediate build files (obj and bin directory)

Look here for more info:

[Difference between Rebuild and Clean + Build in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247457/difference-between-rebuild-and-clean-build-in-visual-studio-2008)

The answers there point out some of the subtleties

Comment: so if I just hit Build then _any changes_ I have made will be reflected in the exe in the bin directory; all unchanged bits of code will be left alone ?