# Visual Studio "Clean & Rebuild" in one button?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My solution i'm working on it's has some specialy. And sometime I need to `Clean solution` and after that `Rebuild solution`, if not the web application can not access. That why I made a `bat` file for that work and bind the bat file to a button in Visual Studio toolbar.

But with that way, visual studio just run the bat file, so it clean and rebuild just one solution I'm defined before in the bat file. What I want is a button which can clean and rebuild on solution OPENING, is made a combo of `Clean` and `Rebuild` commands of visual studio to just one button.

Is there a way for me?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: ["Rebuild" is a "Clean" then a "Build"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247457/difference-between-rebuild-and-clean-build-in-visual-studio-2008). You shouldn't need to explicitly clean then rebuild, afaik.. Are you sure just a Rebuild won't work?

Comment: I'm sure. And work or not it is not important. Similar with my question is: may we combo some of Visual Studio functions into just one button (or menu).

Comment: Can you define external tools in `Tools` menu for that purpose? Say this external tool points to a bat file..

Answer (score 1):

As @Blorgbeard said,

**What is Rebuild Solution?**

Rebuild solution will clean and then build the solution from scratch, ignoring anything it’s done before. What it does is deletes all the assemblies, exe’s and referred files to compile again.

**What is Clean Solution?**

Clean Solution will delete all compiled files (i.e., EXE’s and DLL’s) from the bin/obj directory.

Rebuild means compile and link all source files regardless of whether they changed or not. Build is the normal thing to do and is faster. Sometimes the versions of project target components can get out of sync and rebuild is necessary to make the build successful. In practice, you never need to Clean.

Comment: Thank you written for me. i know what your words mean. But as my comment with @Blorgbeard, what i asking for is about using IDE.