# There is no difference in Android Studio 2.3.3 between Clean and Rebuild, so why have both options in Build menu?

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin

**Why are `Clean` and `Rebuild` identical in AS 2.3.3 and why then are both options found in the `Build` menu?**

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24083753/2737933), there is *no difference* in AS 2.3.3 between `Build` > `Clean` and `Build` > `Rebuild`. Simply checking the `Event Log` verifies this.

So why not modify the AS 2.3.3 `Build` menu to have ONE option, e.g., `Clean and Rebuild`. It's an interesting historical note that `Clean`  used to do something different from `Rebuild`, so that might justify having both in the menu, but it is confusing.

Note that ([supposedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27241056/2737933)) in Visual Studio, the `Clean` and `Rebuild` options do different things, no doubt much like AS did in 1.0.

---

P.S. [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3300) and [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2488) point out that Gradle 4.1 doesn't always interpret commands in the "expected" order. Does this explain why `Clean` and `Rebuild` *must* be the same?

Answer (score 3):

I use clean to update R values while I'm in the middle of coding. I don't want to know that there are errors in my unfinished code, I just want the R file links to be current.

On the other hand Rebuild lists out all the errors.

So behind the scenes they may be the same, but the results are presented in different ways to the user.

Answer (score 3):

@Sam is correct. Looking ONLY at the `Event log` is pretty superficial since it 
only logs events, not details. Looking at the `Gradle console` clarifies it all:

Here's what `Clean`, even with an error in the code I'm compiling:

```
Executing tasks: 
[clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar,
        :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies,             
        :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources,
        :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources,
        :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:clean
:app:clean
:app:    preBuild UP-TO-DATE
(MY NOTE ^^^^^^^^
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout102Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoCore222Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoIdlingResource222Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestExposedInstrumentationApiPublish05Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRules05Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRunner05Library
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
```

`Rebuild` does all that PLUS THE FOLLOWING *IF* there's an error in the code:

```
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:javaPreCompileDebug
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

C:\Users\Dov\Desktop\SQhell\app\src\main\java\com\dslomer64\sqhell\MainActivity.java:221: error: not a statement
x       return true;
^
C:\Users\Dov\Desktop\SQhell\app\src\main\java\com\dslomer64\sqhell\MainActivity.java:221: error: ';' expected
x       return true;
 ^
2 errors

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.398 secs
```

If there is NO error in the code, `Rebuild` does this:

```
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebugUnitTest
:app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugAndroidTestJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:javaPreCompileDebugAndroidTest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 26.83 secs
```

In any event, `Build` performs a `Clean` AND THEN COMPILES the code, terminating if errors are found (and listed); otherwise, doing a full compile.

**So `Clean` DOES differ from `Rebuild`.**

(This means some other posts, like the one listed in Question, have to be modified.)