# Which is more proper to use when? MsVS 2017 Rebuild or Build?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have started programming with Qt Framework using c++ a week ago. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and I am curious about when to use build and rebuild solution.

**I know that Build solution is an incremental build and it only builds the changes and rebuild solution cleans the already built solution and builds again.**

So when to use build solution (maybe clean first then build) and when to use rebuild solution?

I would be glad if someone could explain this to me with giving issues as examples.

Comment: Most of the time "Build" is sufficient. However it worth to run "Rebuild" for the final test to know whether all components are building properly. I believe "Rebuild" invokes "Clear" and then "Build".

Comment: Is the explanation on MSDN not sufficient? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdasz7h.aspx

Comment: There is a subtle difference which is worth being aware of between rebuild and clean + build.
See this previous SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247480/173633
Namely, Rebuild does each project one by one; whereas clean + build will 1st clean them all *then* build them

Comment: There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3095935/4427870) remarkable answer. Also this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3095901/4427870

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Build Solution, Rebuild Solution, and Clean Solution in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095901/difference-between-build-solution-rebuild-solution-and-clean-solution-in-visua)

Comment: @Rishav I have already checked that question and its answers that you've said to be a duplicate of mine. I am not asking what is the difference between build and rebuild. I am asaking which is more efficient/proper to use when?

Comment: @vahancho Thank you for your kind answer it clarified this matter for me a bit. But I would be really glad if other programmers can give some examples to me about this too.

Comment: @stan4th I have already checked that question and its answers that you've said to be a duplicate of mine. I am not asking what is the difference between build and rebuild. I am asaking which is more efficient/proper to use when?

Comment: @KillzoneKid I am not asking what is build or rebuild or clean. So it is not sufficient.

Comment: @BerkUtkuYenisey Does it not explicitly say something like **Choose Build or Build Solution to...** or **Choose Rebuild Solution to...**?

Comment: @KillzoneKid you are right it does say Choose Build or Build Solution to compile only those project files and components that have changed since the most recent build. I am aware of that and I have that knowledge. I am just asaking for a programmer advice on which is more secure or efficient to use when?

Comment: @BerkUtkuYenisey obviously Build is most efficient, but I think the ReBuild and Clean and Build are necessary options when project dependencies are wrong. If there is a sort of cyclic dependency then cleaning all 1st will cause solution not to build. Also, I think these a required because MS tools don't always work as we may wish!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on clarification of question; 
Obviously Build is most efficient, but I think the ReBuild and Clean and Build are necessary options when project dependencies are wrong. If there is a sort of cyclic dependency then cleaning all 1st will cause solution not to build. Also, I think these a required because MS tools don't always work as we may wish!

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I was asking this but everyone thought that I was asking what is build and what is rebuild although I have stated I was not.